# Merge conflicts when everyone adds to CHANGELOG.md file

Tags: git, github

We have a `changelog.md` file.

When you make a change... you can optionally add a line to the top of this file, and it will automatically be included in the release notes when a new app/binary is generated. But we hit merge conflicts for this.

We use github, is there any sort of setting or something that we can do on the file level so that changelog.md uses some other merge strategy so that we stop having these conflicts?

Cheers

**Edit:** I know this could be considered a subjective question, but I suppose I'm trying to put a real-life situation around this problem of "Can I support a better merging strategy for a single file with a setting in git or github?" It seems like this would be fairly common, but I guess not too many other people add to a changelog while developing?

Comment: You mean with a custom merge driver?

Comment: Can the custom merge driver happen on github? i.e. github detects that changelog.md is the merge conflict and it fixes those?

Comment: You can't do that on GitHub today. You can do that with Git today, and there's a merge variant called *union merge* that almost does what you want. But it's the wrong answer for change-logs, which should be *automatically generated from the commits*. (But that's an ideal, not always practical today. Union merge has one problem, which is getting the *ordering* right; automated systems won't.)

Comment: Python core developers created [a tool](https://pypi.org/project/blurb/) that helps them to generate `NEWS` file from https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Misc/NEWS.d. Just an example you're not alone, having conflicts when merging changelogs is a common problem.

Comment: @torek Can one use `--union` only with `git merge-file`? I don't see any reference to the option in `git merge` (or even `git checkout`) man pages.

Comment: @RomainValeri: yes, unfortunately (?) `--union` is only in `git merge-file`, not available as an extended `-X` strategy argument. Given that people wind up unhappy about the ordering that union merge picks, I'm not sure it's actually unfortunate, hence the question mark. :-)

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward to script this locally so that you don't have merge conflicts on the file. Just run the script before creating/completing the PR (if you use PRs), or before the push (if you don't use PRs). If that would be an acceptable (alternative) solution I could write it up.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Looks like union merge would probably be fine for my use case, but it looks like it's not supported by github which kills my idea completely. =(